# How to extract a number from a request.path in Django

Tags: python, django, string

I'm currently looking for a way to extract a number from a request.path in Django. This number is the id of the object. When I print request.path is gives me the following:

```
>>>print request.path 
/post/v2/delete-document/15/
```

I would like to just extract the number 15 since this is the id of the object that is being deleted. I would then make it equal to a variable called object_id:

```
object_id = 15
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: you should be extracting the id as a view method via a URL parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

**EXPLANATION:**

> *First, we split the string by the `/` character, and make sure, that the result doesn't contain any empty strings (that's why we have `if i`) and then get the last item from list `[-1]` and we convert it to an integer with builtin `int()` function*

**CODE:**

```
object_id = int([i for i in str(request.path).split('/') if i][-1])
print(object_id)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
15
```

Comment: that was one of the best answers I've seen on stackoverflow. It was well detailed and I learned something new today. Thank you

Comment: @PeterVatro,  Would you kindly explain for me in details how specifically `if i][-1]` is working?

Answer (score 1):

a slightly different solution than Peter's, using regex to look more explicitely for integers :

```
import re
object_id=re.findall("[0-9]+",s)[-1]
print (object_id)
```